# Webdriver Test failing setup in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, nunit

So this morning I came into work to find that all my tests failed on IE. I ran them locally and watched what was happening. The test are failing to finish the OneTimeSetUp function. I can see the browser open and the test will go to the first page but then it spins until I eventually get this exception

```
------ Run test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.0.8.0 executing tests is started
Running selected tests in C:\git\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\bin\Debug\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.dll
Loading tests from C:\git\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\bin\Debug\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.dll
SetUp failed for test fixture POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite<InternetExplorerDriver>
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:63157/session/343ab5e2-89a4-4f27-bf45-bb12ff91a347/element timed out after 60 seconds.
 ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass13. <ElementIsVisible>b__12(IWebDriver driver)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
 at POMAuctivaTest.AuctivaPageModels.BasePageModel.WaitForElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, By element) in c:\git\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.AuctivaPageModels\BasePageModel.cs:line 143
 at POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite`1.SetUp() in c:\git\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\ExistingUserTestSuite.cs:line 43
--WebException
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
NUnit Adapter 3.0.8.0 executing tests is finished
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:02:06.214) ==========
```

I checked and my assemblies are all up to date. These include Webdriver(2.53()), Webdriver.Support(2.53), IEDriver(2.53), ChromeDriver(2.21), and Nunit(3.2.1). Firefox and Chrome are both working. What is odd is when I watch them I can manually click the first place the test goes, after doing that the tests seem top 'wake up' and finish correctly. Anybody else run into this before?

Comment: Did you just update to 3.2.1? If so, check the packages directory for the presence of folders for older NUnit versions and remove them.

Comment: Additionally, although it's probably not causing your problem, you might want to upgrade to the final release of the NUnit3 Adapter, version 3.0.10.

Comment: Thanks for tip, yeah checked my packages directory and there was still NUnit 3.2.0, not sure why NuGet didnt remove this but I manually did and also added NUnit3 Adapter to the solution. Not sure if this resolved the issue or a little magic but my tests in IE are running this morning. Thank you @Charlie, not gonna lie I got a little 'starstruck' seeing your name. Thank you so much for your contributions to NUnit it is an amazing framework!